# Read a file and comment a line matching a string via shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, sed, grep

**Read a file and comment a line with matching a string via shell script**

I want to comment a matching line of file (final_ip) via shell script

I have a input file (input_ip) if the searching ip is matching on final_ip file, change the file content mentioned below

Before changing :

```
192.168.1.12 #SAM
```

After the change, the matching line must be replacing :

```
# 192.168.1.12 #SAM
```

Comment: If one of the answers has solved the problem, please mark it as accepted using the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '/<string>/s/^/<comment_char>/' <file>
```

`/<string>/` operates on the lines matching `<string>`. `^` operates on the beginning of the line and inserts the comment character.

As I understand you you want to read the IP address from a file. Then you can use the following script. Usage: `script <file_containing_the_IP_address> <file_to_operate_on>`

```
#!/bin/sh

ip_file="$1"
file_to_change="$2"
comment='# '

ip=$(sed 's/\./\\./g' "$ip_file")
temp_file=$(mktemp)

sed "/$ip/s/^/$comment/" "$file_to_change" > "$temp_file" &&
    mv -- "$temp_file" "$file_to_change"

exit 0
```

If the script doesn't need to be portable you can also use GNU sed's `-i` switch.

Comment: Thank you for your support. This is working only if enter it to directly on shell, Is not working on my script, please help.

Answer (score 0):

This uses GNU sed's -i extension to edit the final_ip file in-place:

```
input=`cat input_ip`
sed -i "s/$input/# $input/" final_ip
```

Putting double-quotes around sed's script allows for the $input variable to be interpolated. Only works if there's one IP in the input_ip file.